# How can I access the value from a Vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to make my portfolio using Laravel. I am very new to Laravel. I thought by making a mini project in it will make me familiar with Laravel. Recently, I figured out that Laravel has a dependency on Vue.js

I tried to include jQuery libraries as I am not at all familiar with Vue. But that didn't go so well. Then I started searching for Vue.js but I couldn't find much.

With a lot of effort I made the following Vue component:

```
var trialEle = new Vue({
    el: '#trialEle',
    data: {
        working: 'yes'
    }
});
```

And then I tried to access the value of working by the following markup:

```
<div id="trialEle">
    <h1>Is this working: {{working}}</h1>
</div>
```

But I don't know what I am missing because I am constantly having this error:

[image: Use of undefined constant working]

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @Chamara in the answer below, I have changed `{{working}}` to `@{{working}}`, now there is no error screen.

But still I cannot access the value of `working` from my Vue component.

It is displayed on the page as follows:

```
Is this working: {{working}}
```

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make a separate Vue Component, then import it in a generic js file ex: `main.js`, import `main.js` in your Laravel View 
and then you can use it, example `Example.vue` will contain **template** code of view the `main.js` will have Vue code of rendering data and finally use it in View like `<Example :title="I am awesome"></Example>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @user10415043, but i changed from Vue JS to jQuery only as it was getting difficult to learn Vue because all the tutorials are paid.

Answer (score 0):

`{{}}` is a built in syntax in `blade` if you need to use `vue` `{{}}` inside your `blade` file you need to put `@` in front of the `{{}}`. So like this`@{{working}}`. `@` in blade ignore it as a syntax.

Comment: the error is ignored by using `@`, but I still didn't get the value of working, even though I set it as `yes`

Comment: how do you load vue? through webpack? you have any errors in you console?

Comment: Not helping.. remember i m new to vue, and still a newbie at laravel, can gou please help me by giving the steps so that i can correct this error. Thanks.